# How to insert the column to predict (label)

Tags: c#, ml.net, automl

I am building a multiclass classification program and i want to dynamicaly insert train data from a CSV.

I have tried:

```
var loader = context.Data.CreateTextLoader(
    new[] 
    {
        new TextLoader.Column("sentiment", DataKind.String,0),

        new TextLoader.Column("content", DataKind.String, 1),
    },
    // First line of the file is a header, not a data row.
    hasHeader: true);

var trainData = loader.Load(_filePath);

var experiment = context.Auto().CreateMulticlassClassificationExperiment(240);

//find best model
var result = experiment.Execute(trainData);
Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
Console.WriteLine("Best run:");
Console.WriteLine($"Trainer name - {result.BestRun.TrainerName}");
```

When I run the programm I get this error

> System.ArgumentException: 'Provided label column 'Label' not found in training data.'

I know there is a way to create a class on runtime and pass it as a schema in LoadFromText but I haven't been able to make it work yet.

Comment: Is that the only code you have? You can specify in transforms and in trainers the column name to use which may work for what you want to do.

Comment: @Jon edited more code

Comment: And which version of ML.NET are you using? This looks like it may be an older one.

Comment: @Jon ML.Net Latest stable 1.4.0 and ML.AutoML Latest stable 1.16.0

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you need. In the `Execute` method, there's an overload that it can take in a `ColumnInformation`.

Just create an instance of that and a property on it allows you to specify the label column name.

```
var labelColumnInfo = new ColumnInformation()
{
    LabelColumnName = "sentiment"
};
```

Then, you can pass that into the `Execute` method.

```
var result = experiment.Execute(trainData, labelColumnInfo);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i added the code but the application keeps on running after the specified seconds and never prints out the information about the model

Comment: You can pass in a progress handler that should let you know things are going on. Check [this code](https://github.com/jwood803/MLNetExamples/blob/master/MLNetExamples/AutoML/Program.cs#L27) to see how to use it.